# How to Add Tile Icon in Windows 8 app development?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I started learning Windows 8 app development (I'm a beginner) and I'm making an app where I want to add its tile icon. When I press the window key, then our program exe icon shows as default, but I want to add my own icon. How do I do this?

How do I add an image in this sample code?

```
<Page

x:Class="Calculator.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Calculator"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="Tomato">
    <Button x:Name="btn0" Content="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="458,459,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="458,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="583,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn3" Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="708,390,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn4" Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="458,321,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn5" Content="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="578,321,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn6" Content="6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="708,321,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn7" Content="7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="458,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn8" Content="8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="583,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn9" Content="9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Margin="708,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Click="showbtn"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="Output" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="458,179,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="370" FontSize="24"/>

</Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: You can add it in package.appmanifest

Comment: Here is a small guide how to do it http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/customizing-the-appearance-of-windows-8/240144236

Comment: PleaSe accept an answer if it suits else please clear your doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the default tile image with your own logo image with the path in the package `.appxmanifest`

You can get the guidelines over here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465437.aspx

Hope it will solve your problem